Binance trailing stop loss does not wrok when it's a buy margin order
I use create_order() from python-binance.readthedocs.io as such in the spot account for the SIDE_SELL:
        `order = client.create_order(
            symbol=ticker,
            side=SIDE_SELL,
            type=ORDER_TYPE_STOP_LOSS_LIMIT,
            timeInForce=TIME_IN_FORCE_GTC,
            quantity=quantity,
            price=final_stop_loss,
            trailingDelta=rounded_trailing_delta,
            newClientOrderId=trade_ref
        )`

This works just fine.
I do the mirror version in the margin account for a SIDE_BUY:
        `order = client.create_margin_order(
            symbol=ticker,
            side=SIDE_BUY,
            type=ORDER_TYPE_STOP_LOSS_LIMIT,
            timeInForce=TIME_IN_FORCE_GTC,
            quantity=quantity,
            price=final_stop_loss,
            trailingDelta=rounded_trailing_delta,
            newClientOrderId=trade_ref
        )`

It should work but does not.
The error I receive is
APIError(code=-1102): Mandatory parameter 'stopPrice' was not sent, was empty/null, or malformed.
But 'stopPrice' is not a needed variable when placing a Trailing Stop Order with a trailingDelta. If I put a  stopPrice Binance places a basic Limit Order with a trigger (stopPrice) and an execution price (price)
This is from Binance itself:
Trailing Stop Order Examples ; Excluding stop price
POST 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order?symbol=BTCUSDT&side=BUY&type=STOP_LOSS_LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=0.01&price=42000&trailingDelta=500&timestamp=<timestamp>&signature=<signature>'

Which confirms I should be right.
I am at loss...

I got my answer...
The fail is normal.


Please do not add text as an image for these reasons. Instead, add the text as text. Thanks.
